# Python, Kivy: Buttons not updating text

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to make an app for android that resembles: Would you rather
**(everything in** ***italic*** **is not essential)**
*In the end i made a total of 4 apps (technicaly duplicates) with differences in the kivy code.*
*The original problem was the the buttons with the options to chose from either not triggering the function or the textures disappeared, all that has been fixed.*

The problem i have now, is that the buttons are not updating after they are pressed. The output file is updated, thus the function is called and executed.
The text on the buttons themselves however is not updating after button press.
Here's the code:

```
#Imports
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from os import system as Sys




#Variables
QuestionsDict = {0:["Te faire couper une jambe","Te faire couper un bras"],1:["Lire les penses d'une personne, une fois par jour","Voir jusqu'à un jour dans le futur pendant maximum 1 heure"]}




#Complex variables
try:
    PlayerData = eval(open("TPLocal.dat","r").read()) #PlayerData is a base 3 number 0 = not answered question, 1 = chose option 1, 2 = chose option 2
except:
    PlayerData = str() # if file id not present (1st time opening app)
finally:
    PlayerData = list(str(PlayerData)) #for editing purposes

if len(PlayerData) < len(QuestionsDict):
    PlayerData += "0" * (len(QuestionsDict) - len(PlayerData)) #in case questions have been added to app since last open




#Functions
def b58encode(): #smaller text to send to us for statistical analysis (App is for a e-con student)
    number = int("".join(PlayerData),3)
    alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnoqrstuvwxyz'
    base36 = str()

    while not number == 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, 58)
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return base58




#Classes
class TPGame(BoxLayout): 

    Question1 = StringProperty(QuestionsDict[PlayerData.index("0")][0])
    Question2 = StringProperty(QuestionsDict[PlayerData.index("0")][1])


    def Q1(self):
        PlayerData[PlayerData.index("0")] = "1"
        open("TPLocal.dat","w").write(str("".join(PlayerData)))

    def Q2(self):
        PlayerData[PlayerData.index("0")] = "2"
        open("TPLocal.dat","w").write(str("".join(PlayerData)))

    def copytoclipboard(self):
        Sys('echo|set /p=' + b58encode(PlayerData) + '|clip')


class TuPreferesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TPGame()




#Core
if __name__ in ('__main__','__android__'):
    TuPreferesApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<TPGame>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: u"Tu pr\u00E9f\u00E8res?"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"

    Button:
        background_normal: "Op1.png"
        background_down: "Op1D.png"
        text: root.Question1
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        on_press: root.Q1()

    Button:
        id: B2
        background_normal: "Op2.png"
        background_down: "Op2D.png"
        text: root.Question2
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "center"
        valign: "middle"
        on_press: root.Q2()

    Button:
        background_normal: "Black.png"
        background_down: "Black.png"
        text: "Si vous voulez nous envoyer vos reponses\n Appuyez ici"  #translates to "if you want to sent us your answers press here"
        text_size: self.size
        halign: "center"
        valign: "bottom"
        on_press: root.copytoclipboard()
```

I wasn't able to change the text on the buttons every time you press a button. I tried with *Clock* and *setter* but without success.
What i want to do is update the text on the first two buttons to show the next two options to choose from. (the will be more questions later in the QuestionsDicts, unlimited amount)
Sorry, the text in the app is in french (I'm french)
Thanks in advance
Steph

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe you should bind your button to some function which will update text?
Like

```
Button(on_release = do.something) # do.something is a function
```

or in .kv file:

```
button:
on_release: root.something
```

Of course you can also use on_press but this will cut fancy animation of pressed button

EDIT:
Ok, I was wrong and now I have a questions:

```
def b58encode(*args): #smaller text to send to us for statistical analysis (App is for a e-con student)
number = int("".join(PlayerData),3)
alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnoqrstuvwxyz'
base36 = str()

while not number == 0:
    number, i = divmod(number, 58)
    base36 = alphabet[i] + base36
return base58
```

Where is base58? when I use clipboard i have an error maybe I should be base36?

ok maybe this: 
Kivy file

```
<TPGame>:
orientation: "vertical"
button2: B2
```

and main.py file:

```
class TPGame(BoxLayout):

Question1 = StringProperty(QuestionsDict[PlayerData.index("0")][0])
Question2 = StringProperty(QuestionsDict[PlayerData.index("0")][1])
button2 = ObjectProperty()
...
def Q2(self):
    PlayerData[PlayerData.index("0")] = "2"
    open("TPLocal.dat","w").write(str("".join(PlayerData)))
    self.button2.text = 'PRESSED'
```